# Why is my stdin redirection ('<') not working with subprocess.Popen()?

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I'm building a script in python, and one part of it needs to send an email with a file as the message body. Instead of sending the contents of the file, the script sends me the next character entered into the terminal e.g. if I enter c as a part of "cat", it doesn't put c into the terminal, but instead sends me an email with "c" as the body.

This is on CentOS 7.6.1810, with Python 3.5.6.

```
#!/usr/src/Python-3.5.6/python
import subprocess
import sys
import os

subprocess.Popen(["mail", "-s", "Test Subject", "myemail@myemail.com", "<", "/path/to/file.txt"], stdout=open('stdout', 'w'), stderr=open('errout', 'w'))
```

The contents of file.txt should be send as the body, but I just get the first letter of whatever the next thing I type is. "stdout" reads "EOT" after this, and nothing is printed to "errout". To be clear, I'm trying to invoke the command

```
mail -s "Test Subject" myemail@myemail.com < /path/to/file.txt
```

from inside of the script. This command works as expected outside of the Python script, but inside of it I run into the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen()` executes your new process directly by default. So your code passes some additional arguments `<` and `/path/to/file.txt` to the `mail` executable, which will not yield the expected result.

Redirections like `<` on unix systems are handled by the shell, not by each individual executable. That's why you want `subprocess.Popen()` to run your `mail` command with all the arguments `mail` as well as the redirection `< /path/to/file.txt` in a shell instead.

You can do this with the `shell=True` parameter:

```
subprocess.Popen(["mail", "-s", "Test Subject", "myemail@myemail.com", "<", "/path/to/file.txt"], stdout=open('stdout', 'w'), stderr=open('errout', 'w'), shell=True)
```

Note that the shell is probably not necessary – you could have `Popen` open the file and connect `mail`'s `stdin` to that descriptor, see anishsane's comment below.

Using a shell should be avoided especially if user data is being passed to the child process, as it would need to be sanitized properly to prevent command injection attacks.

See the [Python 3 docs on subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: Alternately, `subprocess.Popen(["mail", "-s", "Test Subject", "myemail@myemail.com"], stdin=open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r'), stdout=open('stdout', 'w'), stderr=open('errout', 'w'))`

Comment: @anishsane yes, of course, thanks. note added to answer.

Comment: `shell=True` is generally considered risky, because it is prone to shell injection attacks. So, avoid it as much as possible. Having said that, you can use it if the command to be executed is trusted. (i.e. it is not generated using external/user inputs.)

Comment: @anishsane True, but it doesn't look like it in this case. Note on that added too nonetheless.